# How do I archive Windows MSBuild artifacts in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: windows, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I have defined part of my script like this:

```
stage 'Archive'
archive includes: 'Job\\Project\\bin\\Release\\*'
```

It does not give an error message, but neither can I find the artifacts in the UI. How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This incantation subdued the Jenkins Pipeline into archiving the artifacts:

```
stage ('Archive') {
    archiveArtifacts 'SolutionFolder\\ProjectSubFolder\\bin\\Release\\*'
}
```